# Mininet network errors when configured by tc

Tags: python, mininet, packet-loss

I am trying to specify packet loss by tc command on interface (port) 1 of switch part of network I have created using mininet : 
`sudo tc qdisc change dev s1-eth1 root netem loss 0.1%`
but gettring error:
**`RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument`**

Any help would be appreciated.

**Network Details:**

It is a tree topology based mininet network on Ubuntu 14.04 with depth = 2 and fanout = 5. On first level, a switch is connected to 5 switches which are connected to 5 hosts each. All switches are OpenvSwitch.

**Mininet network:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from functools import partial
from mininet.cli import CLI
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.log import setLogLevel
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import OVSKernelSwitch
from mininet.node import RemoteController
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.util import dumpNodeConnections


class MyNet( Topo ):
    "Simple topology example."

    def __init__( self ):
        "Create custom topo."

        # Initialize topology
        Topo.__init__( self )

        # Add hosts
        h1 = self.addHost( 'h1' )
        h2 = self.addHost( 'h2' )
        h3 = self.addHost( 'h3' )
        h4 = self.addHost( 'h4' )
        h5 = self.addHost( 'h5' )
        h6 = self.addHost( 'h6' )
        h7 = self.addHost( 'h7' )
        h8 = self.addHost( 'h8' )
        h9 = self.addHost( 'h9' )
        h10 = self.addHost( 'h10' )
        h11 = self.addHost( 'h11' )
        h12 = self.addHost( 'h12' )
        h13 = self.addHost( 'h13' )
        h14 = self.addHost( 'h14' )
        h15 = self.addHost( 'h15' )
        h16 = self.addHost( 'h16' )
        h17 = self.addHost( 'h17' )
        h18 = self.addHost( 'h18' )
        h19 = self.addHost( 'h19' )
        h20 = self.addHost( 'h20' )
        h21 = self.addHost( 'h21' )
        h22 = self.addHost( 'h22' )
        h23 = self.addHost( 'h23' )
        h24 = self.addHost( 'h24' )
        h25 = self.addHost( 'h25' )

    # Add switches
        s1 = self.addSwitch( 's1' )
        s2 = self.addSwitch( 's2' )
        s3 = self.addSwitch( 's3' )
        s4 = self.addSwitch( 's4' )
        s5 = self.addSwitch( 's5' )
        s6 = self.addSwitch( 's6' )

        # Add links
        self.addLink( s2, s1 ,bw=0.1)
        self.addLink( s3, s1 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( s4, s1 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( s5, s1 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( s6, s1 ,bw=100)

        self.addLink( h1, s2 ,bw=0.1)
        self.addLink( h2, s2 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h3, s2 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h4, s2 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h5, s2 ,bw=10)

        self.addLink( h6, s3 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h7, s3 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h8, s3 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h9, s3 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h10, s3 ,bw=10)

        self.addLink( h11, s4 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h12, s4 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h13, s4 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h14, s4 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h15, s4 ,bw=10)

        self.addLink( h16, s4 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h17, s4 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h18, s4 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h19, s4 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h20, s4 ,bw=10)

        self.addLink( h21, s6 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h22, s6 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h23, s6 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h24, s6 ,bw=10)
        self.addLink( h25, s6 ,bw=100)

topos = { 'MyNet': ( lambda: MyNet() ) }
#sudo mn --custom MyNet.py --topo MyNet --controller=remote,ip=10.0.0.1,port=6633 --switch ovsk,protocols=OpenFlow13 --link tc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this [link](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/a38896c254897e77b61a6b049a3c8007a1317a14/mininet/link.py#L280), it seems that mininet uses `tc` commands to set `packet loss`, `delay` etc. internally.

It tries to overwrite the qdisc file, therefore, it errors **`RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument`**.

To set packet loss set it in `mininet` script itself by using `loss` parameter while creaqting a link. For an example see [this](https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/simpleperf.py#L30).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to solve the problem you have. But I know you can specify delay and loss rate in mininet API.

Have a look at line 29 below: 
https://github.com/mininet/mininet/blob/master/examples/simpleperf.py

Comment: Isn't that causes packet loss before even queue overflows?

Comment: I think yes, that packet loss is due to link failure or etc.

Comment: Are you looking in a failure in different part of network ?

Comment: drops could happen in the link due to link failure (e.g. link is cut etc). Or drop could happen in switch due to overflow or etc. right ?

Comment: I read from mininet code that it uses tc qdisc internally to simulate packet loss, does ovs switches also use this?

Comment: I know that mininet uses ovs switches by default. So I guess ovs uses this too.